# Some good texts for integral equations

Tags: reference-request, integral-equations

I am really interested in the theory of integral equations and I am just starting out on the reading. However, I am wondering what could be the best texts to look for (and from where, if possible). Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "Theory of integral equations" is extremely broad. Are you looking for techniques to solve them? Are you looking for deep theory?

Comment: @CameronWilliams, sorry about that but I am talking about how to solve them (though I think there are no general methods for solving). And so I would be interested in both the deep theory and how to solve texts.

Comment: As for how to solve, the text *Handbook of Integral Equations* is really good. It has *lots* of different classes of differential equations and their solutions. As for deep theory.. there will likely not be any satisfactory text as integral equations are incredibly difficult. A good text might be Halmos' and Sunders' text *Bounded Integral Operators on $L^2$ Spaces*.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I liked ***Differential and Integral Equations*** by Peter Collins (2006).